# Pig: Max Value per Bag of Tuples

Tags: apache-pig

So I have some data like the following:

```
grunt> describe aliveevents_patient_id;
aliveevents_patient_id: {group: int,aliveevents: {(events::patientid: int,events::eventid: chararray,events::etimestamp: datetime,events::value: float,mortality::patientid: int,mortality::mtimestamp: datetime,mortality::label: int)}}
```

How exactly would I be able to get the biggest value per group of etimestamp?

Essentially I'd like to do this to the following:

```
patient_id, etimestamp
1, 10
1, 20
2, 30
```

Outputs

```
patient_id, etimestamp
1, 20
2, 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question :

let aliveevents_patient_id contain two field {patient_id,etimestamp}

then the script is :

```
A = GROUP aliveevents_patient_id BY patient_id;
DUMP A;
(1,{(1,10),(1,20)})
(2,{(2,30)})

B = FOREACH A GENERATE group,MAX(aliveevents_patient_id.etimestamp);
DUMP B;

(1,20)
(2,30)
```